# How can I display each picture in a row in ipython(jupyter) notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a directory with some pictures which I need to read and display.
I wrote this, but what it does, is weird, it doesn't display any images until the loop is over! as if it buffers everything and then flushes it! the line numbers however work fine! meaning they are printed as the loop goes on, and when the loop is over, you see lots of images getting displayed on the cell! 
here is the code :

```
import os
%matplotlib inline
img_dir = 'G:/deep-visualization-toolbox/input_images3/'
i = 0
for file in os.listdir(img_dir):
    img = caffe.io.load_image(img_dir+file)
    print '{0})'.format(i)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
    i+=1
```

and output :

```
0)
1)
2)
3)
4)
5)
6)
7)
...
```

> C:\Users\Master\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:524:
>   RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created
>   through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained
>   until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control
>   this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
>   max_open_warning, RuntimeWarning)

```
21)
22)
...
168)
First image 
second image 
third image 
....
```

How can I get rid of this problem and get the images to show as they are fetched?

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` does not take effect inside the `for-loop`. You will need to call `plt.show()` after `plt.imshow(img)` inside the `for-loop`. Otherwise, `%matplotlib inline` will only be applied after you have exited the `for-loop`.

Comment: @Abdou: Thank you very much, please post that as anwer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing the plots in the expected succession is because `%matplotlib inline` does not take effect inside the `for-loop`. Therefore you will need to add `plt.show()` right below `plt.imshow(img)` to force the figure to be shown. The following is how I would do it:

```
from glob import glob
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


%matplotlib inline


img_dir = 'G:/deep-visualization-toolbox/input_images3/'

i = 0

for img_file in glob(img_dir+'*'):
    img = imread(img_file)
    print '{0}'.format(i)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    i+=1
```

I hope this helps.